# CSS Checkbox styling unique classes

Tags: html, css, input, label

Is there a good way to select an `input` that has unique classes.

At the moment this will do...

`input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {....}`

But what if I want to grab the label by the class name `usethis`? *Code below* -

```
<div class="checkbox">
   <input id="c1" class="rounded-input" type="checkbox" rel="performance" onchange="change()" />
   <label class="usethis" for="c1">Performance</label>
</div>
```

Comment: where have used the class name usethis ?

Comment: I've edited my snippet its on the `label`

Comment: It's not clear what it is you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .usethis {
  color: red;
  font-size: 5rem;  // i have given some random styles here
}
```

This style will only come when the checkbox is checked, and if you have another checkbox in the page without the label having the class .usethis, this style wont be applied to those checkboxes

Comment: Awesome, I was concered that removing `label` in the selector would mess it up. Thanks

Comment: Happ to help you